# Django: Filter for Product Colour

Tags: django

I am trying to create a filter for product colours.

Products are imported by csv and each colour drastically varies e.g camo, lilac, auburn.

I want to create a filter with a selection of standard colours e.g red, blue green.

When one of the standard colours is selected, I would like to query the database and return all products that contain that colour (or that are in that colour category).

For instance if the colour blue was selected, the filter would return queryset of any products that contained the colours: blue, teal, turquoise, cyan, denim.

I have tried to do this with django filter (choices) but have been unable to come up with a solution.

Does anyone know the best approach for this?

**current product model**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    aw_deep_link = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    aw_image_url = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    search_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    merchant_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    display_price = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')
    brand_name = models.ForeignKey('Brand', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    size = models.ForeignKey('Size', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    colour = models.CharField(max_length=500, choices=COLOURS, default='')
    rrp_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    category = TreeForeignKey('Category',null=True,blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default='')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

**current filters**

```
import django_filters 
from .models import Product, Brand, Category
from django.forms import CheckboxSelectMultiple

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    search_price__gt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='search_price', lookup_expr='gt')
    search_price__lt = django_filters.NumberFilter(name='search_price', lookup_expr='lt')
    brand_name = django_filters.filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter( label='Brand',widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple, queryset = Brand.objects.all())
    colour = django_filters.filters.MultipleChoiceFilter(choices=COLOURS, widget=CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['colour', 'brand_name']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have individual shades of colours, and then you have categories of colours.

What you need is a way to map a category of colours like "blue" to a list of shades like ["blue", "teal", "turquoise", "cyan", "denim"]

One way to do this would be with a dictionary

```
shades = {
 "blue": ["blue", "teal", "turquoise", "cyan", "denim"],
 "red": ...   
}
```

Then you allow users to select from the list of base colours, but you map that to the list of shades before searching. Assuming 'colour' contains the users choice (Blue, Red, etc.)

```
Item.objects.filter(colour__in=shades[colour])
```

This has the benefit that individual shades like 'violet' can be in the list for 'blue', 'red' and 'purple'.

If you want to map shades to colours dynamically rather than hardcoding a dictionary then you can store the colours and shades in the DB, or even in a json file.